# dbDelta using Foreign key not working on update

Tags: plugin-development, dbdelta

I am using FOREIGN KEY with dbDelta when activating the plugin (register_activation_hook()). It works great when creating the table for the first time, but outputs an error when updating the table (the table is already present but an alteration has to be done on the table). Any suggestions?

```
    if(GLOBAL_PLUGIN_VERION != get_option("GLOBAL_PLUGIN_VERSION")){
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE `".TEST_TABLE."` (
     `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL,
     `description` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
     `location_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
     FOREIGN KEY  (`location_id`) REFERENCES `".TEST2_TABLE."` (`id`)
    );";
   }
```

Error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in wp-admin/upgrade.php on line 1568
>
> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY  (`location_id`) REFERENCES
>   `test2` (`id`)' at line 1 for query ALTER TABLE
>   test ADD COLUMN FOREIGN KEY  (`location_id`) REFERENCES
>   `test2` (`id`) made by ...
>
> WordPress database error Multiple primary key defined
>   for query ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) made by...

Answer (score 1):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table):

> Note that the dbDelta function is rather picky, however. For instance: [...]
>
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".TEST_TABLE." (
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    location_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    FOREIGN KEY  (location_id) REFERENCES ".TEST2_TABLE." (id)
);";
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the apostrophes but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you update your question with more context?  When you call dbDelta, what are the conditions (`if( xyz ) { dbDelta( $sql ); }`) ?